# Docker experimental version on Red Hat

Tags: docker, build, redhat

I have a Red Hat machine on an AWS cloud. I installed Ansible and Docker (experimental version as the community edition cannot be installed now on Red Hat). Now I am runnig a simple command to check whether Docker works:

```
ansible local -m shell -a "docker pull hello-world"
```

I'm getting the following error:

> localhost | FAILED | rc=1 >>
>
> Using default tag: latest
>
> Warning: failed to get default registry endpoint from daemon (Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?). Using system default: https://index.docker.io/v1/Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?

When I use

```
sudo ansible local -m shell -a "docker pull hello-world"
```

> ```
> localhost | UNREACHABLE! => {
>       "changed": false,
>       "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).\r\n",
>       "unreachable": true
> }
> ```

I have tested Ansible by copying a file into local host and it works fine whereas with Docker I'm facing this issue. Is there anything I am missing or anything that needs to be setup for Docker's experimental version?

Comment: Try this `ansible local -s -m shell -a "docker pull hello-world"`

Comment: Thanks its working as expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to run ansible through sudo but tell ansible that it should run the command using sudo. That can be done by adding the `-s` flag

```
ansible local -s -m shell -a "docker pull hello-world"
```